# Stream with FFMpeg with a Decklink card on Windows

Tags: windows, streaming, ffmpeg

I am trying to capture with ffmpeg the output from a Decklink Studio card on Windows, how would this be done? Is this even possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure. You just need to use the [DeckLink SDK](http://www.blackmagic-design.com/support/sdks/).

Comment: Thanks, but what exactly would I do when I have the SDK?

Comment: I don't know exactly Karl, that's why there is SDK documentation.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg -video_size 720x576 -rtbufsize 702000k -framerate 60 -pixel_format uyvy422 -framerate 25 -f dshow -i video="Decklink Video Capture":audio="Decklink Audio Capture"  -format x264 -an -b:v 1200k -s 1280x720 -f flv "rtmp://yourURL/Key"
of course it depends on the streaming protocol.